# java basic multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Why does the code below is not a deadlock and works fine?

```
public class Concurrent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Concurrent my = new Concurrent();
        my.method1();

    }

    private synchronized void method1() {
        System.out.println("method1");
        method2();
    }

    private synchronized void method2() {
        System.out.println("method2");
    }
}

Output:
method1
method2
```

When I call method1() monitor is locked. JVM or compiler can not call method2() because this method is also synchronized by monitor of "my" object. But it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why doesn't the code in the Question deadlock?

Because primitive mutexes (monitors) are reentrant.  When a thread that is within a given mutex attempts to acquire it again, it does not block.

[JLS 17.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1):

> "A thread t may lock a particular monitor multiple times; each unlock reverses the effect of one lock operation."

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, I thaught that if I need a reentrant lock I should use java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock. Also, I thaught that the code in my Question is deadlock but jvm or compiler "optimize" my code to prevent the deadlock.